# amp distorts on clean setting

Tags: electric-guitar

I use a Boss GT6 into a Fender Deluxe Reverb Tonemaster amp. Im having a problem with my amp distorting on the clean setting. To get the cleanest sound, should I turn the output up on the GT6 and turn the amp volume down, or visa versa?

Comment: How does it sound if you leave out the GT6? That’s what I’d check first. If it’s clean, then your problem is with the signal from the GT6. If not, it’s the amp.

Comment: @wabisabied the GT6 can output much hotter signal than normal guitar effects (I checked the specs) so clean signal from it can still overdrive the amp

Answer (score 9):

If your amp distorts on clean settings then either your amp is broken or you are inputting a signal that is far too hot for your preamp. Try turning *down* the output of your effects device and increase the output of your power amp. Hopefully this would solve the situation. If the amp is broken you need to get it replaced or repaired.

Answer (score 5):

A very obvious start point is to take the GT6 out of the equation. Then listen to what just amp and guitar do. You may well have the *gain* (the pre side of the amp) up too high anyway, which often, with a lot of amps, will overdrive the signal, producing a distorted sound. That will most likely need turning down.

If all that works, all well and good. If not, why not try GT6 into another amp, along with another guitar. It's a process of elimination: take each part of the jigsaw at a time. Yes, even the two leads - guitar to GT6, and GT6 to amp. Unlikely to be those, but always worth getting them a clean bill of health.

If another guitar into the same amp, with gain down, retains the distortion, then it's sadly going to be the amp that's ailing.

Answer (score 4):

This amp will start to distort on its own in two circumstances: hot signal coming into the front of the amp and if the volume is around 4 (or so) or higher.

While both can be quite pleasing and desirable in many circumstances (lots of cool clean tones are actually a little distorted), if you are looking for no amp distortion, try:

- making the GT6 output so-called "unity gain" where there is no change in volume when the GT6 is off or on
- keep your amp volume under 4 (you can adjust the output wattage on the back to higher wattage to keep the volume control under 4 but increase overall volume)

Once satisfied with the clean sounds using the above, feel free to adjust the GT6 and/or amp to taste.

Have fun! I love my Tonemaster Deluxe Reverb :)

Comment: +1 for toggling GT6 on/off to test output gain. The output gain knob is on the back beside the left/right+phones outputs. Most factory photos show the output knob at 1/2-way between min/max and wondering if this is the "unity" position. Manual doesn't say. If the OP uses this knob for headphone listening, they may have cranked it up. Make a GT6 preset with no effects attached to test the output level.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments and suggestions, if the guitar and amp alone sound distorted:

1. Test the guitar on a known, clean amplifier. I've seen guitars with damaged pickups or bad wiring distort.
2. If the issue lies with the amplifier, an easy check is to see if the cones are torn before assuming the circuitry is faulty.